# Not able to send links in email after setting header

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html-email

I am not able send links in email.
I am using `wp_mail()` function to send email.
When i set header `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; \r\n";` this header removes `href` attribute in received email.

i am using wp_editor for textarea. I also tried html textarea but the result was same.

When i send mail without setting header, i am getting anchor tag as text.
`<a href=\'http://example.com\'>Example</a>`

here is my code.

```
jQuery('.for_email').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var mail_data = jQuery('.email_popup_form').serialize();
        //console.log(mail_data);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
            data:'action=mail_link_popup&'+mail_data,
            success:function(res)
            {
                //console.log(jQuery('#mycustomeditor_afds_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').html());
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is php code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_link_popup','mail_link_popup');
function mail_link_popup()
{
//  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; \r\n";
    wp_mail($_REQUEST['to_email'],$_REQUEST['subject'],$_REQUEST['message_test'],$headers);
}
```

Here is HTML form

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="email_link_myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class='row'>
              <div class='container'>
              <div class='col-md-9'>

                <form class="form-horizontal email_popup_form" role="form">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">To:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control to_email" id="email" name='to_email'>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">From:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                      <input type="email" class="form-control send_email" id="pwd" name='send_email' >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="sub">Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control subject" id="sub" name='subject'>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group"> 
                      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="sub"></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                          <?php 
                          $content = '<div class="cont_test"></div>';
                            $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor_afds';
                            $settings = array(
                            'media_buttons'=>false,
                            'textarea_name'=>'message_test' ,
                            'editor_class'=>'add_link_test' ,
                            'media_buttons' => false,
                            'quicktags'     => TRUE
                            );
                            //wp_editor( $content, $editor_id ,$settings);

                          ?>
                        <textarea class='cont_test' name='message_test'></textarea>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default for_email">Send Email</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the code.
I just added message body in `stripslashes()`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_link_popup','mail_link_popup');
function mail_link_popup()
{
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8';
    wp_mail($_REQUEST['to_email'],$_REQUEST['subject'],stripslashes($_REQUEST['message_test']),$headers);

}
```

And it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how content header works in Wordpress. You need to set header through add_filter

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'setHeader' );
wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', '<a href="http://some.com"></a>' );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'setHeader' ); 

function setHeader(){
    return 'text/html';
}
```

P.S. Do not forget to reset content types.

Comment: Thank you for reply. i already tried this but it's not working.  Anything missing in my code?

Comment: why you are concatenating `headers` ? `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; \r\n";` . Use like this `$headers = "Content-Type: text/html;";`

Comment: it's just copy and paste. do you think it's the issue?

Comment: yes it could be, and another thing i noted from your code is this line `var mail_data = jQuery('.email_popup_form').serialize();` did you try to console.log this if it returning the data or not ?

Comment: yes i am receiving the content perfectly. and i tried setting header by this `$headers = "Content-Type: text/html;"` but this is not working

Comment: One last thing you can try is setting email headers in an array `array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',)` or this could be the problem with the server settings itself

Comment: Thanks for your help.
finally i had solve the issue. just put the message body in stripslashes()

Comment: That's great. Post your solution as an answer and accept it, so others can benefit from the solution